# Will Panasonic WF950 Wireless On-Ear Headphones work with Ubuntu?

Tags: sound, hardware, headphones, compatibility

I just wondered if (shot in the dark) anyone knew if [these wireless headphones](http://www.argos.co.uk/static/Product/partNumber/9004203.htm#pdpFullProductInformation) would work with Ubuntu? I was thinking if the transmitter is USB then I might not get the drivers.

Does anyone have any ideas of a way I could find out without paying for them then finding out I can't use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work on 3.5mm jacks. So yes, it should work.